# Does Elemental Affinity let you add your Charisma modifier to the damage of cantrips?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, class-feature, sorcerer, cantrips

The [Draconic Bloodline sorcerer](https://www.dndbeyond.com/characters/classes/sorcerer#DraconicBloodline)'s 6th-level feature, Elemental Affinity, lets you add your Charisma modifier to the damage when you cast a spell. Does this count with cantrips such as *fire bolt*?

Comment: [A review of chapter 10](http://media.wizards.com/2018/dnd/downloads/DnD_BasicRules_2018.pdf) might be helpful when pondering the details of spell casting.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

## Yes it does, because cantrips are spells

Specifically, cantrips are 0th level spells. From the PHB:

> Every spell has a level from 0 to 9. A spell's level is a
> general indicator of how powerful it is, with the lowly
> (but still impressive) *magic missile* at 1st level and
> the earth-shaking *wish* at 9th. Cantrips - simple but
> powerful spells that characters can cast almost by rote - are level 0.

Since cantrips are spells, and Elemental Affinity lets you add your Cha mod to damage when you cast a spell, Elemental Affinity applies to cantrips (that deal the appropriate type of elemental damage, of course).

Comment: You might add that there is a specific piece of rules language it uses when it means 'spells but not cantrips', where it'll say "a spell of level 1 or higher" (or some such thing, I don't have my book at the moment).